# React Native const value changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, variables, scope

In my React-Native App; I have one const variable declared as below in one component named: `constants.js`

`export const IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK = false`

Now,

In my `Splashscreen.js` I am doing as below:

`constants.IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK=true;`

When I try to access the value of IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK in the same `Splashscreen.js` or any other functional component I get the updated value- true.

How is it possible?

**[Update]**

here is my constants.js file which I am using to declare global constants.

```
 export const IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK = false 
 export const isLoggeedIn = 0 
 export const T1= “Test1” 
 .  .  .  .  .  
 export const T2= “Test1”
```

so when I need any of the above constants to be used, I import the constants.js in the specific component and then I do have the access of the variable.

Comment: You are probably using a transpiler or bundler (or something else in your build chain) that messes with the exports and converts them into an unfortunately mutable object. This should indeed not be possible, assigning to `IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK` should throw an exception according to the spec.

Comment: What exactly is that `constants` object? How were you importing it?

Comment: constants is one component where I have initialized different constants and this IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK is one of them.
I import it as 
`import * as constants from '../config/constants';`

Comment: So what build tools are you running? Did you debug what kind of value `constants` is at runtime?

Comment: @Bergi I edited my question, if that helps you to understand. The constants here is the component and constants.{variable}-> This is how I am using its value.

Comment: Yes, that is understood. But in a native ecmascript module environment, `constants.IS_VIA_DEEP_LINK=true;` would throw an exception. So again, what build tools are you using? Can you show us the transpiled code?